# Run a function on each sheet of an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

It should not run on the first sheet, and then run on all other sheets. It should get stock closing data for each stock, which is the name of the sheet.

```
Sub Dosomething()
    Dim xSh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            With ws.UsedRange
                Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("A1:A1").Formula = "=STOCKHISTORY(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),TODAY()-5*365,TODAY(),0)"
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you

Update-

```
    Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("A1:A1").Formula = "=STOCKHISTORY(""" & ws.Name & """,TODAY()-5*365,TODAY(),0)"
```

Is being applied to all the cells, however has @ sign in front of the formula is not running

Comment: You should probably explain what you mean by "not working" - are you getting an error or something?

Comment: If you need to include quotes inside a string then they need to be doubled-up: `.Formula = "=STOCKHISTORY(MID(CELL(""filename"",A1),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",A1))+1,255),TODAY()-5*365,TODAY(),0)"`   But you don't need to do that parsing in the formula - you can use ws.Name directly: `.Formula = "=STOCKHISTORY(""" & ws.Name & """,TODAY()-5*365,TODAY(),0)"`

Comment: SideNote: `With ws.UsedRange` isnt being utilized. If you're not getting your intended output, that might be why.

Comment: To avoid the implicit intersection operator `@` assign to `.Formula2`

Comment: Also, `Worksheets(ws.Name).Range` is redundant.  Just use `ws.Range`